# Mathematica incorrectly imports a table

Tags: import, list-manipulation

I am trying to calculate the eigenvalues of a large matrix (10^4x10^4), which is formed by summing a matrix containing advective terms and a matrix containing diffusive terms. I am using the following simple script:

```
add = "address/n=50l=50/";
adv = Transpose[Import[add <> "u_B.dat", "Table"]];

diff = Transpose[Import[add<>"diffusion.dat", "Table"]];

ans = 303*adv + diff // Eigenvalues;
Sort[ans]
```

Mathematica imports the diffusion matrix as a one dimensional array for some reason, and as such cannot transpose it or calculate eigenvalues. I have used this code for various (smaller) resolutions/matrix sizes and it worked fine. I really do not understand why this matrix is suddenly being imported as a one dimensional object.

> ----------Edit 2---------

Here is a link to the diffusion file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gx8sokt2zggiq99/diffusion.dat?dl=0

---

Here are the first few elements of the first row. There are 10^4 rows and 10^4 columns in the file (adv has the same)

```
  -9.9999999999997868      -2.0718235518950072      -0.7368652300812841      -0.3366733737341420      -0.1785767012502300      -0.1046968732429871      -0.0659813101416420      -0.0439219818289296      -0.0305217022632576      -0.0219581437532483      -0.0162554151475518      -0.0123258483194475      -0.0095389926277596      -0.0075132770178053      -0.0060091173707776      -0.0048712446774423      -0.0039962212568781      -0.0033134493535647      -0.0027736997195499      -0.0023419799843653      -0.0019929858760674      -0.0017081324330329      -0.0014735758787324      -0.0012788706178710      -0.0011160417221390      -0.0009789342582586      -0.0008627502850535      -0.0007637149330716      -0.0006788326779994      -0.0006057073883789      -0.0005424080705597      -0.0004873676971277      -0.0004393062644368      -0.0003971718205800      -0.0003600948026407      -0.0003273525133293      -0.0002983412085359      -0.0002725540935550      -0.0002495637478567      -0.0002290081574144      -0.0002105794044882      -0.0001940145717756      -0.0001790883002599      -0.0001656067401675      -0.0001534025872206      -0.0001423309440523      -0.0001322659628047      -0.0001230979832230      -0.0001147311994253      -0.0001070816570830       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000       0.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Can you paste first few columns and rows from your file? Maybe it is not what you think it is.

Comment: I should add, if I display a part of the diff table it looks fine {{},{},....{}}, just like the adv table, but when I ask Mathematica what its dimensions are it gives me only 1 dimension (10^4)..

Comment: To help debug this problem it is important to know the `Dimensions[]` of the matrices **immediately** after the `Import[]` but **before** the `Transpose[]`. Could you check if it is what you think it should be. Also the arrays you import, are they square? `Eigenvalues[]`  by default requires a square matrix. I don't see how `303*adv + diff ` is square unless **both** `adv` and `diff` are also square.

Comment: After importing the dimensions are {10'000,10'000} for `adv` (irrespective of transposition) and {10'000} for `diff`, which is odd, because when I print it it looks like it should have the same dimension as `adv`. Sorry I made a mistake earlier, the file does not have 250000 elements, that's just the number of characters.

Comment: It's going to be nearly impossible to diagnose this without the file - it could be as simple as two numbers running together and freaking out the interpreter or one row with a different number of entries. If you could upload it somewhere someone can probably help. If you don't want to do that, I would try using `OpenRead` and `ReadLine` and then `StringSplit` and `ToString` to get your data in the proper form - it will be a little more work, but it will make it easier to figure out where things go wrong.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try that. I've linked the file above.

Comment: It seems somthing is wrong with the format of the diffusion data file. In which case the fault is not with Mathematica. To check this you should try importing it as `"Text"` and see how that goes.

Comment: An alternate method for checking is to use `ReadList["diffusion.dat", String, NullRecords -> True]` and see what the list of lines looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why this is occurring, but there are 4 lines which are each short by one number. You can see the line numbers below:  9850, 9900, 9950, 1000.

```
diffusion = Import["diffusion.dat", "Table"];

(* save the import in case its needed later *)
DumpSave["diffusion.mx", diffusion];

(* is it nxn? *)
Dimensions@diffusion

(* {10000} *)

(* no, what lengths are present? *)
Length /@ diffusion // Union

(* {9999,10000} *)

(* where are the short lines? *)
lengths = Table[{n, Length[diffusion[[n]]]}, {n, Length[diffusion]}];
Select[lengths, #[[2]] == 9999 &]

(* {{9850,9999},{9900,9999},{9950,9999},{10000,9999}} *)
```

Edit:  Further, this can be used to examine line 9850 as a string:

```
stream = OpenRead["diffusion.dat"];

Skip[stream, "String", 9849];

rec9850 = ReadList[stream, "String", 1]
```

In a section of that string you will see a run-together number:

[image]

Sorry, another edit, but this problem is too interesting. Assuming this run-together at the minus sign is the issue, it can be corrected by putting a space in front of all the minus signs:

```
SetStreamPosition[stream, 0];

strings = ReadList[stream, "String"];

correctedStrings = StringReplace[#, "-" -> " -"] & /@ strings;

diffusion2 = 
  ReadList[StringToStream[#], "Number"] & /@ correctedStrings;

diffusion2 // Dimensions

(* {10000,10000} *)
```

And:

```
eigenValues = Eigenvalues[diffusion2];

Histogram[eigenValues, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]